# libreoffice calc graph | scale in relation to each row of data

Tags: graph, scale, libreoffice, calc

I have a list of data by year with expenses for each topic, eg.

> ```
>              2014    2015 ...
> expenses 1     12      14
> exp. 2        321     339 
> exp. 3     43'334  42'991
> ```

As the different rows do have different scales, i.e. some are in the 10 some in the 1000s, I want a line graph that shows all data in relation to the scale of each row.
But with one scale for all data, most lines are flat at the bottom, while a few show up meaningful.
The graph should show the differences over time, i.e. if the curve remains flat, everything is the same, if it goes up and down, it shows changes.

Basically, it can be done by doing a graph for each row and then stacking the images over each other.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use a column that calculates the averages of each row.
2. Use columns that calculate the relative value of each expense, for example in percent, in relation to the average of its row.
3. Use these relative values for your diagram.

|  | 2014 abs | 2015 abs | ... | Average | 2014 rel | 2015 rel | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| exp.1 | 12 | 14 | ... | ... | ..% | ..% | ... |
| exp.2 | 321 | 339 | ... | ... | ..% | ..% | ... |
| exp.3 | 43'334 | 42'991 | ... | ... | ..% | ..% | ... |

You can add the columns to the same table or create a new table.

Comment: I did that but some that 5000%, others just 10% variations.

Comment: I guess I have to make single graphs for each of them.

Comment: Then use some other reference, the maximum for example. You see, it all depends on the data, and you did not present a lot. ;-)